# After button postback (Server side) jquery dialog moves to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a jquery dialog that opens up.  On it are some server side drop down lists that have `AutoPostback` set to `true` because they cascade and fill other drop down lists after a postback.  I maintain keeping my dialog open after a server side post back by making use of a hidden field and setting it to 1 if I need to keep the dialog open or 0 if I want to close it.

Heres the jquery test to see hidden field value:

```
 if ($("#MainContent_hdnOpenContactCompany").val() === "1") {
                $("#dialogContactCompany").dialog("open");
            } else {
                $("#dialogContactCompany").hide();
            }
```

So my issue is not that I do not have the dialog open, my issue is when Im scrolled down a page and I open a dialog, the minute I do a postback the dialog moves to to the top of the page.  So the user cannot see it unless he / she scrolls to the top.

I tried adding this, (http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/240/jquery-dialog-position-problem-web-form-postback), but I believe the author has a set width...but this did not work for me.

```
 //Company dialog
            var pos = new Array();
            pos[0] = ($(window).width() - 880) / 2 +
                       parseInt(theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value);
            pos[1] = 100 + parseInt(theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value);

            $("#dialogContactCompany").hide();
            $("#dialogContactCompany").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                appendTo: "form:first",
                position: pos,
                width: 880,
                height: 'auto',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#dialogContactCompany').css('overflow', 'hidden'); //this line does the actual hiding
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    //if someone x's out (Closes the dialog) we better make sure we
                    //set the hidden field to 0 so that the dialog doesn't open up again on post back
                    $("#MainContent_hdnOpenContactCompany").val("0");
                }

            });
```

Mainly the `pos` information to maintain a position but that too does not work.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this we had to use document.scroll.
Here is a great article: http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/jquery-tutorial-scroll-ui-dialog-boxes-with-the-page-as-it-scrolls/